# Unable to edit my audiences in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: audiences

I know this has been posted in the past, but I have tried everything to edit an audience that I just finished creating.  I have all the rights, I've even logged into Central Admin as the farm account and still unable to edit an audience.  Any help would be appreciated.  Oh and I understand how to manage and edit them, but the arrow option just doesn't show up.  Thanks in advance

Comment: are you trying from Server? did you try in different browser? for me more scripting error in browser

Comment: Good point, let me try from the server, and also from Firefox and see if that makes a difference.  stay tuned

Comment: Yep, it works from the server.  Great job!  I guess I should have tried that first.  Thanks

Comment: Iknow, i had same issue in past. i just added that as answer for community benifit and my points :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not permission issue, rather it is more about the Scripting issue in browser.Following things to try.

- try with different browser.
- If you are not on server then Open the central admin from server.